# Get column value after searching for row in dask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that I converted to a dask dataframe using the `from_pandas` function of dask. It has 3 columns namely `col1`, `col2` and `col3`.

Now I am searching for a specific row using `daskdf[(daskdf.col1 == v1) & (daskdf.col2 == v2)]` where `v1` and `v2` are values that I am searching for. But when I try to fetch the value of `col3` using `daskdf[(daskdf.col1 == v1) & (daskdf.col2 == v2)]['col3']` it gives me a dask series structure and not the column value.

In pandas I could do `pandasdf[(pandasdf.col1 == v1) & (pandasdf.col2 == v2)]['col3'].tolist()`. How do I fetch the value of `col3` here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `.compute` will convert a `dask` object into `pandas` object, so the following will give the required result:

```py
result = daskdf[(daskdf.col1 == v1) & (daskdf.col2 == v2)]['col3'].compute().tolist()
```